# pi4 hypervisor, handle irq

Tags: arm64, raspberry-pi4, hypervisor

I am working on hypervisor with raspberry pi 4B board.
when I study interrupt virtualization,  I encounter a problem, I am follow this document
[url][https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102142/0100/Virtualizating-exceptions[/url]](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102142/0100/Virtualizating-exceptions%5B/url%5D)

[quote]There are two mechanisms for generating virtual interrupts:

1 Internally by the core, using controls in HCR_EL2.
2 Using a GICv2, or later, interrupt controller.
[/quote]
I use method 1. Everything worked fine, I can route IRQ to my EL2 code, and I can forward it to EL1 Linux kernel.

But, when I tested, I tried to disable IRQ from EL1, use "msr   daifset, #0xf", after this, IRQ will not trigger to EL2 also.
I am confused, because the document above said pstate.I will only affect vIRQ(for EL1) not pIRQ(EL2). I tested a GPIO interrupt and IPI interrupt, both failed.

I search the web, there are few article on this topic, and can't find any additional settings.
All document I found, said set I bit in EL1, will not affect EL2/3.

Thanks, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts involved in interrupt handling, interrupt routing and interrupt masking. Setting PSTATE.DAIF to 1, will mask the interrupt(but there are some conditions) and HCR_EL2.AMO,IMO,FMO will route the interrupt to EL2 from EL1 or EL0.

1. If you are at EL1/EL0, HCR_EL2.{IMO,FMO,AMO} are set to one then interrupts cannot be masked using PSTATE.DAIF bits. In this case interrupt will be delivered to EL2. Here it's assumed HCR_EL2.{E2H, TGE} are zero.
2. If you are at EL1/EL0, HCR_EL2.{IMO,FMO,AMO} are set to zero, then interrupts can be masked using PSTATE.DAIF bits.
3. If you are at EL2, HCR_El2.{IMO,FMO,AMO} are set to zero, irrespective of PSTATE.DAIF bits interrupt will not be delivered. If these are set to one then PSTATE.DAIF bits can mask the interrupt.

Similarly there are controls in SCR_EL3.{EA,IRQ,FIQ} which when set to one will route the interrupt to EL3 from EL2, EL1 or EL0. Above rules hold good here as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My code is doing like you said in "1", I set IMO, FMO, AMO to 1,  I can get interrupt in EL2, and forward interrupt to EL1(linux kernel) by set VI bit (of course, not just set VI bit). All above work fine, the raspios works very well. I am sure interrupts really route to EL2.
But, when I test, I set DAIF to 0xf in kernel(EL1), and after that, my EL2 will not get any interrupt on this core, and later I clear DAIF, interrupt can goes to EL2 again. It seems the DAIFset in EL1, also affect the EL2's interrupt, this against all the related doucuments I found. 
Thanks.

Comment: I tested with DAIF set to 0xF and interrupt can still go to EL2. Here I've made sure IMO, FMO and AMO are still set to 0x1.

Comment: I've tested on Arm provided FVPs and not on Raspberry Pi 4